# Is it possible to "capture funds" for authorized credit card transactions via the API?

Tags: bigcommerce

It is possible to set up your Bigcommerce integration with a credit card processor (e.g. Braintree) such that the payment is only authorized by default and a second step is required to capture the funds.

Bigcommerece leaves these transaction in an "awaiting  payment" status and provides UI to initiate the capture of said funds via the admin interface.

Is there a way to capture funds on a specific transaction using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as of today. You cannot capture funds via API.

Answer (score 0):

Not through the API, but if you have your orders page open, then you can send a JavaScript call through the browser. In this example orderNumber is the order you want to capture

```
var myLinks = document.getElementById('content-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('capture-trigger '); 
for (i = 0; myLinks.length; i++) {
   if (myLinks[i].getAttribute('data-order-id')==='" & orderNumber & "') {
       myLinks[i].click();
   }
}
```

You also need to click the confirm button (or simulate a return keystroke).