# Capture Funds for Authorized Cards via API on Big Commerce

Tags: api, payment, authorize.net, bigcommerce

Currently, payments processed through certain credit card processors (example: Authorize.net) can be set to first authorize the fund, then later capture them when prompted in the UI via the admin interface.

I am hoping to capture funds of authorized orders (Big Commerce status 'awaiting payment') via the API rather than through the UI. I have not been able to find anything but a post from 3 years ago saying it was not yet possible. Is there now a way, or is this still something that cannot be done?

old thread: [Is it possible to "capture funds" for authorized credit card transactions via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182697/is-it-possible-to-capture-funds-for-authorized-credit-card-transactions-via-th)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to capture funds via the API today. The API is meant to Create, Read, Update, or Destroy entries and nothing is exposed to the API that would allow you to execute an action between BigCommerce's core application and the payment gateway .

Comment: Is this still not possible? please let me know. I found a post in your forum of bigcommerce there you mentioned about you are looking into exposing more functionality in this area.